# Could not satisfy Django application requirements

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I have been trying to run a Django application since afternoon. The application probably uses Python 2.7. I have created virtual environment and I have installed Django with Python PIP package manager. However, this application requires JQuery package for proper working. Unfortunately, an error has occurred when I tried to install JQuery package with PIP:

```
(my_env) user➜~/carcaresilesia» pip install jquery    [16:39:44] ⚡[..........]
Collecting jquery
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/45/9a6d7ff770b1279c901c8dfca1f9a9d6c9822d75a2bad834d0e2ddd4f8cd/jquery-1.2.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-wKwd78/jquery/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from turbogears.finddata import find_package_data
    ImportError: No module named turbogears.finddata

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-wKwd78/jquery/
```

I tried install the turbogears package, unsuccessfully with below error:

```
(my_env) user➜~/carcaresilesia» pip install turbogears
Collecting turbogears
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/35/80872474a6663b6994b6879041a38b2fa81a34098e331f2ffddd43e2c8d3/TurboGears-1.5.1.tar.gz
Collecting CherryPy>=3.1.2 (from turbogears)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/6d/d0d951dee5ba50900eccb71ef501a847d0392f50056d36234740f97a2ef8/CherryPy-14.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ConfigObj>=4.3.2 (from turbogears)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/61/079eb60459c44929e684fa7d9e2fdca403f67d64dd9dbac27296be2e0fab/configobj-5.0.6.tar.gz
Collecting FormEncode>=1.2.1 (from turbogears)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2f/53/707c2b9b65ea6bedde67c21cbf7c71394f4a198620d4e9c1771214b91dcc/FormEncode-1.3.1.tar.gz
Collecting Genshi>=0.4.4 (from turbogears)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c5/2f/34493b2286561d0ea003c568a6c80343eee3c9975a69964d22ce8501dd3f/Genshi-0.7.tar.gz
Collecting PasteScript[cheetah]>=1.7 (from turbogears)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/7d/ddc3efab0967e7056bcd6adea0b860717b4b6e4d3ea8ec49985ed0f43cb0/PasteScript-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Ignoring Cheetah: markers 'extra == "Cheetah"' don't match your environment
Collecting PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2555 (from turbogears)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2555 (from turbogears) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PEAK-Rules>=0.5a1.dev-r2555 (from turbogears)
```

How can I satisfy these dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

Your project almost certainly doesn't rely on the [python package jQuery](https://pypi.org/project/jquery/), since it appears to be for turbogears, which is a completely different web framework to Django.

If your templates require jQuery then you should download and add it to your static files, or use [a CDN](http://code.jquery.com/).